# Deletimg a file in media directories?

Tags: android

I have a `File` object named `file`, which points to a file in any of media directories (`DIRECTORY_DCIM`, `DIRECTORY_MUSIC`, `DIRECTORY_MOVIES`, `DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`). When I am calling `file.delete()` method it fails to delete the file. However, it works if the file points to files on other directory. Any solution for this?

Comment: do you have write access for you application ?

Comment: Yes I have write access.

Comment: and what does your `File#delete()` return?

Comment: it returns false.